# Can I use two OR/AND in the same time in one statement?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have this statement

```
 <?php

    if($item['option_1049'] == 'Ready Property' OR $item['option_1049'] == '现房' AND $item['option_4'] == 'Sale')
         {
                echo _ch($item['option_1002']); echo '&nbsp;'; echo '{lang_psqft}' ;
                echo '<br>';
                echo _ch($item['option_1068']); echo '&nbsp;'; echo _ch($options_prefix_1069); echo _ch($item['option_1069']); echo _ch($options_suffix_1069);

          }

               ?>
```

but it seems like this is not working?

Because I want to show echo values which has value of **ready property** and **sale** I have OR because I'am doing a double language so in this case this  if I switch another language still my meet my conditions.

This is posible in this way??

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but you must use parenthesis to specify the divisions. For instance, `(a or b) and c` or `(a and b) or c`

Comment: @aynber Got it thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to make this easier. The 2nd argument to `in_array()` would be an array list with all the translations.

```
if( in_array($item['option_1049'], ['Ready Property', '现房'] && $item['option_4'] == 'Sale') {
    //code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the of the order in which your conditions are evaluate, use parenthesis.

```
if(($item['option_1049'] == 'Ready Property' OR $item['option_1049'] == '现房') AND $item['option_4'] == 'Sale')
```

Also, it is seen as bad practice to use the OR and AND keywords. Mainly because of they do not have the same code execution precedence as `||` and `&&`